# Can Azure Function v1.x be updated to use Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.x?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm working to update our Azure Blob Storage (WindowsAzure.Storage) packages from the depreciated 9.3.3 version to the Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob replacement. This requires an update for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs: v2.2.0 to v3.0.x. After completing the package update and the following signature revisions to the azure functions; it will no longer run because of the following Error (Revision 1) caused by the TraceWriter:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'traceLog' to type TraceWriter. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).
```

I then attempted to convert it to ILogger (Revision 2), and got a similar error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'traceLog' to type ILogger. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).
```

**Question**

Can Azure Functions v1.x be updated for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs from v2.2.0 to v3.0.x? Or is Azure Functions v1.x dependant upon Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs v2.2.x? What configuration am I missing to connect the log?

**Environment**

```
Azure Functions = 1.38 
Target Framework = .NET Framework 4.8
```

**-Original-**

```
[FunctionName("PlaceOrder")]
public static void OrderImport([BlobTrigger("pending/{filename}", Connection = "storage")]Stream inputBlob, string filename, TraceWriter traceLog)
```

**-Revision 1-**

```
[FunctionName("PlaceOrder")]
public static void OrderImport([Blob("pending/{filename}", Connection = "storage")]Stream inputBlob, string filename, TraceWriter traceLog)
```

**-Revision 2 (with ILogger)-**

```
[FunctionName("PlaceOrder")]
public static void OrderImport([Blob("pending/{filename}", Connection = "storage")]Stream inputBlob, string filename, ILogger traceLog)
```

Comment: Microsoft talks about moving from 1.x to newer versions in their docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#migrating-from-1x-to-later-versions Also .NET Framekwork is not supported for 2.x +

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to do is [migrating your Function version from 1.x to later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#migrating-from-1x-to-later-versions), and modify your code.

As we can see from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#supported-versions), `Function 1.x` support `.NET Framework 4.7`, while `.NET Framework 4.8` is not supported.

And,

> While it's possible to do an "in-place" upgrade by manually updating the app configuration, going from 1.x to a higher version includes some breaking changes. For example, **in C#, the debugging object is changed from TraceWriter to ILogger.**

Here is a simple example about `ILogger`, for more information you should go to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#supported-versions):

```
public static class SimpleExample
{
    [FunctionName("QueueTrigger")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("myqueue-items")] string myQueueItem, 
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

Tips: Check the `TargetFramework` version and `AzureFunctionsVersion` version and `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions` NuGet version in `.csproj` file.

Comment: 1) Thank you for the links. Upgrading from 1.x to a greater version would also require an upgrade to .NET Core (and re-writing a large portion of the application with corresponding libraries like Authorization and Entity Framework). That's far out of scope on this effort.

2) I appreciate the link to the docs. We're successfully running on 4.8 and it works fine. The docs are outdated.

Question: Is there an update path for WebJobs / non-depreciated Azure Blob Storage libraries within the Azure Function v1.x / .NET Framework 4.8 constraint (that does not require a .Net Core upgrade)?

Comment: For this requirement, you could raise a support ticket on azure portal. You could create the ticket by following the steps on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request